# Javascript code works in Jsfiddle but not in Local browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a portfolio website. And I came into a problem while scripting my java code. I tried to troubleshoot for hours on end but to no avail. Then I just decided to make the simplest code to see if it was just me that was being a total idiot. Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $("p").hide();
 
 $("h1").click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Hi.</h1>
<p>How are you?</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jtest.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help??? Maybe I'm just linking it to the HTML wrong or something. It might just be a simple solution I'm not figuring out.

Comment: is `jtest.js` linking correctly?

Comment: Check the network tab to see if everything loaded. Also check the console for any errors

Comment: If your root directory where you are hosting the HTML file also has the jtest.js in the same directory, then it looks fine, but if you have the jtest.js in a subdirectory, that might be why it doesn't run.  Try opening the javascript console or similar (e.g. scripts, network tab) to see if it's returning a 404 not found for the js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check make sure your browser has JavaScript Engine turned on.
2. Make sure you include all the files name correctly.
3. Put scripts inside head tab
4. Sometimes Internet Explorer disables scripts from running it gives you a warning

Comment: i tried both the head tab method and the body tab method. I made sure the javascript engine is turned on. I even tested it on different websites. Everything has been checked and double checked and the code still won't work. It's pretty amazing actually.

Comment: Ah. yes, There is a slight discrepancy in the file names. Thank you!